# image on Iphone 2 times bigger then I specified

Tags: html, iphone, css, mobile

I have an image on my page and I set the image size via CSS to specific size but when I open the page in Iphone the image appear 2 times bigger then the size I set.

What could be the reason for that and how to fix?

Comment: check if you have autolayout/resize etc enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the resolution and the size of the iPhone.
use different stylesheet for mobile devices.

ex :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
  href="mobiledev.css" />
```